# Windows patching is automatic or manual

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

Might be you guys never encountered anything like this. Here are the situations.
We have around **2500+ servers** (**win 2003/2008/2012**). Monthly Windows patching done by two way.

1. Assigned the patch to servers by **SCCM/WSUS/BSA**, then login manually on the server and download and install the patches. After installation reboot the server. This is a manual patching in our terms.
2. Assigned, download and install the patch to servers by **SCCM/WSUS/BSA** and then reboot the server manually. We called this as Automatic patching.

Now i have to prepare list of servers by patching type (**Manual & Automatic**).

**Is there any registry key or anything where i can check windows patching is automatic or manual?**

Once i get that info then i will create a script and run on all the server.

Can anybody advise me on this?

Comment: What research have you done on your own?

Comment: i checked registry and also checked group policy. but not able to find this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
```

> ```
> AUOptions
> Range = 2|3|4|5
> 2 = Notify before download.
>
> 3 = Automatically download and notify of installation. 
>
> 4 = Automatically download and schedule installation. Only valid if values exist for ScheduledInstallDay and ScheduledInstallTime.
>
> 5 = Automatic Updates is required and users can configure it.
> ```

from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939844(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try and let you know the status. Voted Up,